# Trouble Loading image/Jquery Drag & Drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, load

I am currently coding my own drag and drop puzzle game. I have it set up to where you only have to specify the number of rows/cols you want and the image source.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#container').puzzle(3,'/images/guitar.jpg');
</script>
```

The problem I am having is that when the page first loads, the puzzle is either not there or flattened. However, whenever you load again, it works fine. I'm pretty sure the reason it isn't working is due too my image not loading fast enough, but I do not know how to fix it

You can view my game here at http://jsfiddle.net/bRgTv/

You can view my code at http://dursigns.com/misc/puzzle/js/puzzle.js

Also when playing my game, the draggable blocks sometimes have about 1-2px gaps between each other. If anyone can steer me in a better direction to fixing that too, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out

```
 var img      = $("<img/>").attr({
                    "src": source,
                    'class': 'img'
                })
                .load(function() {
                    w       = this.width;
                    h       = this.height;                      
                    width   = cont.width();
                    rem     = width%size;

                    if(!once){
                        if(rem > 0){                            
                            width  = cont.width() - rem;
                        }else{
                            width  = cont.width();                              
                        }
                        height = width/(w/h);
                        $(cont).prepend(img);
                        $(cont).append('<ul id="inner" style="width:'+width+'px; margin: 0 auto;" />');
                        $('#inner').css({
                            'width': width,
                            'min-height': height
                        });
                    }
                    once = true;
                    $(this).hide();
                });
```

Check out my game so far at http://dursigns.com/misc/puzzle